# How to retrieve steam market price history?

Tags: python, steam, steam-web-api

I'm trying to get price history for items on steam market. I found a link that returns price history for a specific item (which is mentioned in almost every question about getting price history from market at this site).

http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=PT&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Falchion%20Case

It works fine in browser while I'm logged-in in Steam, but when I try to do the same thing in python, it returns an empty list (the same thing happens when I try to do it in browser while not being logged-in in Steam). This is my python code (uses requests lib):

```
import requests

params = {'country': 'RU', 'currency': 5, 'appid': 730, 'market_hash_name': 'Falchion%20Case'}
data = requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory', params=params)
print(data.text)
```

So, the question is: is there any way to emulate being logged-in in Steam while making requests in python (or some other language)?

Comment: You could do it with javascript, using your browser session.

Comment: @Hacketo, thank you for the suggestion, it led me to the idea that I can use cookielib and python to emulate browser session. I'm going to try if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `Cookie` key `steamLogin` to your session id. You can perform login on your browser and get this value.

```
cookie = {'steamLogin': '76561198058933558%7C%7C2553658936E891AAD'}    
data = requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=PT&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Falchion%20Case', cookies=cookie);
```

I have used a random `steamLogin` value here, change it to your session id.

You can try performing login from through python as well, but you might want to turn off steam guard for making things simpler. I would have demonstrated performing login automatically, but I don't wish to disable my steam guard and get a 15 day trading restriction.

Comment: how do i get the steam login value?

Comment: @FistOfFury For Chrome, settings > advanced > content settings > cookies > see all cookies and site data > find steamcommunity.com > find "steamLoginSecure" > copy the "Content" string

Answer (score 4):

Where it says `{'steamLogin':'...'}`, it should be `{'steamLoginSecure':'...'}`. So the correct code would be:

```
cookie = {'steamLoginSecure': '76561198058933558%7C%7C2553658936E891AAD'}    
data = requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=PT&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Falchion%20Case', cookies=cookie)
```