# How to set cookies for an backend API call with laravel

Tags: python, php, laravel

So I am making an application for myself where I have a price history graph of an single steam market item. But the API I am calling needs a cookie called steamLoginSecure. There is an example on how to do this in Pyton ([How to retrieve steam market price history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961868/how-to-retrieve-steam-market-price-history)). But I want to do this in Laravel as I am building my application in Laravel.

This is the API link that I am trying to call: https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=PT&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Falchion%20Case

What I have tried so far:

```
    Route::get('/getPriceHistory/{marketHashName}', function ($marketHashName) {
    $cookie = Cookie::make('steamLoginSecure', 'xxx', 3600);
    return Http::get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&currency=1&appid=252490&market_hash_name=Fish%20Hammer")->headers->setCookie($cookie)->json();
    });
```

And

```
Route::get('/getPriceHistory/{marketHashName}', function ($marketHashName) {
    return Http::get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&currency=1&appid=252490&market_hash_name=Fish%20Hammer")->withCookie(cookie('steamLoginSecure', 'xxx', 3600))->json();
});
```

xxx represents the token this is steam user based.

Comment: You are looking for [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#request-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Guzzle` and its methods:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

$cookieJar = CookieJar::fromArray([
    'steamLoginSecure' => 'xxx'
], 'steamcommunity.com');

$url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&currency=1&appid=252490&market_hash_name=Fish%20Hammer';

$response = Http::withOptions([
    'cookies' => $cookieJar
])->get($url);

dd($response->json());
```